# JMeter : IF condition in the controller is not working

Tags: jmeter

I have a BeanShell Sampler in which I decide/set a path out of 3 paths (See the picture). But the control never comes into the following IF condition at all. I don't know what am I missing?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl1am.png)

[image]

Comment: In the previous step: I have BeanShell sampler SET PATH where I set the value of flag like:   vars.put("flag","1");

Comment: Try using `${__jexl3("${flag}" == "1")}` as if condition

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How do I add another condition?

Comment: `${__jexl3("${flag}" == "1" && "${flag2}" == "2")}`

Comment: Thanks, ararar. When I had a my Beanshell PreProcessor inside my IF condition before a HTTP POST it didn't work but when I changed it from Beanshell PreProcessor to Beanshell sampler or JSR223 it worked. I am not sure when to use what or what is the difference between these 3?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't use Beanshell, since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead) for scripting
2. Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into scripts, either use "Parameters" section of the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or go for code-based equivalents. Replace this line (at least)

   ```
   if ( ${matchNr} >= 20 )
   ```

   with this one:

   ```
   if ( (vars.get('matchNr') as int) >= 20)
   ```
3. If your script doesn't do what it  is supposed to be doing most probably there should be a relevant message in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), either look into it yourself or include it in the question if you don't understand what's going on there